# How to read value from csv and use it in query?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a csv file that has a video names like `111`, and I have the following query:

```
select data
from table
where name = 111;
```

How to create a loop that goes through the file, read video name and paste it to the query?

Comment: either `copy csv to table` or use fdw to read it...

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should show at least minimal effort to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Use the CSV module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer as vague as your question, but might help.

```
input_file = 'exampleFile.csv'

with open(input_file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        query = "SELECT data FROM table WHERE name = %s;" % line.strip()
        #and then
        #pass_query_to_postgresql(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is to use pandas to read it as a DataFrame.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("filepath")
query = list(df)
```